# Why am I receiving a notice string offset in this php code?

Tags: php

i am writing a code for email.

```
enter code here:-

 <?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   if(!empty($_POST['sendto'])) {
foreach($_POST['sendto'] as $check) {
     echo $check[0]; // error :Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\smart_class_Ctr\email.php on line 15
     echo "<br>";  
     echo $check[1];            
     }

    }
}
```

?>

```
 <form method='post' action=''>

Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br/>
Message:<br/>
<textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
</textarea><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="sendto[]" value="1" />Student
<input type="checkbox" name="sendto[]" value="2" />Staff

<input type='submit' value="submit" name="submit" />
```

Any help as to why this is happening (or why it's created an infinite loop) would be appreciated!

Please suggest me how to slove this problem.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Because **$check is not an array**

use this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   if(!empty($_POST['sendto'])) {
       foreach($_POST['sendto'] as $check) {
          echo $check; //now you see values
          echo "<br>";  
       }
    }
}
```

**If you want to get first value of you post** use :

```
$_POST['sendto'][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print_r($_POST);` to see the entire contents of the `$_POST` superglobal array. That'd help you see where you're going wrong. Here's an example:

```
Array
(
    [subject] => Subject
    [message] => Some sample message.
    [sendto] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [submit] => submit
)
```

You're using a `foreach` loop to loop through `$_POST['sendto']`. `foreach` automatically grabs the array value, so you do not need to specify the array index. In other words, `$check` is not an array, it's the value itself. So you'd the following instead:

```
foreach($_POST['sendto'] as $check) {
    echo $check;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try  `echo $check;` NOT  `echo $check[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the:

```
echo $check[0];
```

Use the below code:

```
echo $check;
```

If you want the key and value both then use this:

```
foreach($_POST['sendto'] as $key => $check) {
   echo $key." = ".$check;
}
```

here $key will have the value of index.